# Failed to load image at '/images/logo.png': timeout: timed out in html to pdf by weasyprint

Tags: django, html-to-pdf, weasyprint, django-weasyprint

**This is weasyprint log file output**

> Anchor defined twice: 'sec-dec'
> Failed to load image at 'http://localhost:8000/static/assets_landing/images/logo.png': timeout: timed out
> No anchor # for internal URI reference
> No anchor # for internal URI reference
> Anchor defined twice: 'sec-dec'
> Anchor defined twice: 'sec-dec'
> Failed to load image at 'http://localhost:8000/static/assets_landing/images/logo.png': timeout: timed out
> Failed to load image at 'http://localhost:8000/static/assets_landing/images/logo.png': timeout: timed out
> No anchor # for internal URI reference
> No anchor # for internal URI reference
> No anchor # for internal URI reference
> No anchor # for internal URI reference

```
<img id="pdf-logo-2" src="{% static 'assets_landing/images/logo.png' %}" alt="#" />
```

I face issue when render pdf from html. In weasyprint log, it show

> Failed to load image at '/images/logo.png': timeout: timed out